# JerseyTest and JUnit throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, junit4, jersey-2.0, overriding

I have some problems with the jersey test framework. If i use the @Before and @After annotations, then the target method throws a NullPointerException.
I thought JerseyTest works with JUnit? Where is my problem?

- Jersey: 2.12
- JUnit: 4.11

Code that fails:

```
public class MyResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() { }

    @After
    public void tearDown() { }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void SHOULD_RETURN_BAD_REQUEST() throws IOException {
        System.out.println(target("myPath"));
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Result:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:566)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:580)  at
>   foo.bar.MyResourceTest.SHOULD_RETURN_BAD_REQUEST(MyResourceTest.java:43)

Code that works:

```
public class MyResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void SHOULD_RETURN_BAD_REQUEST() throws IOException {
        System.out.println(target("myPath"));
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
JerseyWebTarget { http://localhost:9998/myPath }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your methods seem to override some important initialization made in parent `JerseyTest`.
Try to name them differently. E.g.:

```
@Before
public void setUpChild() { }

@After
public void tearDownChild() { }
```

Comment: Just for reference: setUp() and tearDown() are the names autogenerated by Netbeans for the Before and After methods. Renaming these solved the problem for me (with NB 8.1 and Jersey 2.22) so this is still relevant.

Comment: Good to know, wasn't aware of that it is generated. Not using Netbeans. That explains higher interest in this question.

Comment: What a great catch! I was going nuts on this one!

Answer (score 20):

I came here because I was using JUnit 5 and it seems that it wasn't seeing the @Before and @After annotations on the JerseyTest setup/tearDown methods. I had to override them and use the new JUnit 5 annotations

```
public class MyResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @BeforeEach
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @AfterEach
    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void SHOULD_RETURN_BAD_REQUEST() throws IOException {
        System.out.println(target("myPath"));
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the corresponding bug report (open since 2017-09): https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3662